# Can we re-open the question about keeping a beard while searching for a job?

Tags: discussion

[Can I keep my beard while interviewing?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74136/can-i-keep-my-beard-while-interviewing)

This question was recently closed as "Too Broad."  Personally I don't feel that it is too broad, and I think that the answer could potentially be helpful to others who may have similar questions in the future.

This question was closed by a diamond moderators vote, so I'm not sure.  Is it even possible to re-open the question?  If it is possible,  would the community considering re-opening this question?

Comment: I suspect the context of the question may have influenced the decision (which I fully support as being the right choice) to close the question before it started attracting trash.

Answer (score 5):

See [Monica's comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74136/can-i-keep-my-beard-while-interviewing#comment206049_74136):

> What industry? Where are you in the world? Are there cultural conventions
>   about beards (or their absence)? Please edit in more details. I'm
>   putting this on hold temporarily so people don't spend energy on
>   answers based on wrong guesses; once you edit it'll be reviewed for
>   reopening. Thanks.

Basically there are a lot of unknowns in the question right now, so she put it on hold before people fill in the gaps incorrectly. The intent is to reopen it once the question has been edited some more.

Comment: After seeing that, I did edit the question slightly to include OP's comments since the question was closed.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I think this needs input from the OP before it can be reopened. There's a world of difference between working with heavy machinery in a strongly secular country and working in a religious institution a strongly Muslim country.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I hope that OP returns to make the edits, but I disagree that they required for this to be a useful question.  [This related question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13216/are-beards-perceived-as-unprofessional-in-the-workplace) makes no mention of the industry or the culture, yet it has some great answers.

Answer (score 3):

The "too broad" close reason doesn't mean a post can't fit on our site; instead, it simply means the post won't fit on our site *in its current format.*

**["Too Broad" Close Reason](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):**

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Without details, answerers must make too many assumptions about an askers situation in order to provide an answer.  Many of these assumptions may be incorrect, which means the answers have a greater chance of not being useful to the asker. What's more, because there are more possible "answers", this increases the chance of more noise on the site, and reducing noise is one of the fundamental goals of Stack Exchange.

Thus, the asker should edit the post to add details. If you want to help, you can ask questions in the comments to help clarify and "tease" the details out of the asker. Once done, you or other members of the community may edit the post to add in these details. Once edited, the post bumps to the top of the questions page where it becomes more visible to the community. This increases the likelihood it will receive attention and get reopened.

I see potential in this question; we just need to help the asker help us focus on *his* specific problem he's facing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it closed.

Basically the question is 'Should I make a big deal about being a Muslim in interviews'. The beard is really secondary. And there's not enough information to address the question properly.